# Specific sculpting brushes causes asymmetrical results

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

Im having some issues sculpting.
So far, I have noticed this issue occur in two different sculpting tools, one being "Smooth" and the other one being "Clay". Most other brushes do not have any issues, and a simple workaround for my issue is to hit the "Symmetrize" button, however I'd like to find out what's going on with my Blender.
I've tried to reinstall it completely, and it still did not help.

First, heres the mesh Im trying to smooth. Its supposed to be the base of a tail. I want to smooth the bottom right part.
[image]

When doing so, despite making sure everything was located and scaled correctly, and the proper options enabled to sculpt symmetrically, it fails to do so. Picture below.
[image]

Same thing occurs for the Clay brush.
[image]

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this? Im completely lost on what Im doing wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your issue here. You are sculpting with a x-axis symmetry, which looks like it's working. What is it you are trying to achieve VS what you just showed us ?

Comment: Its not working. If you look closer, especially at the bottom picture, it is not symmetrical. Its slightly off. Its as if its trying to make it symmetrical but it doesnt follow through entirely.